# React why its rerender altough I use react.memo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have list with Recyclerlistview where you can click on a item then a modal is open and in the modal are items with flatlist. So if I open the modal its rerenders 2-3x. And if I scroll or click its rerenders again. But why ? I use react.memo

Recyclerlistview

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { RecyclerListView, LayoutProvider, DataProvider } from 'recyclerlistview';
import I18n from 'i18n-js';
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';
import { ModalUppinfo } from '../../modal/uppinfo/modalUppinfo';
import { ModalDrops } from '../../modal/drops/modalDrops';
import { map1boss, map2boss, otherboss } from '../../../utils/mockData';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const Bosses = ({ data }) => {
  const modals = Array.from({ length: 8 }).map(_ => React.useRef(null).current);

  const [uppRef, setUppRef] = React.useState([]);
  const [dropRef, setDropRef] = React.useState([]);

  const openModalDrop = React.useCallback((dropdata) => {
    setDropRef(dropdata);
    modals[3].open();
  }, [modals]);

  const provider = React.useMemo(() => {
    return new DataProvider(
      (r1, r2) => {
        return r1 !== r2;
      }, index => {
        return 'index: ' + index;
      }
    )
  }, []);

  const dataProvider = React.useMemo(() => {
    return provider.cloneWithRows((data === 1) ? map1boss : (data === 2) ? map2boss : otherboss);
  }, [provider, map1boss, map2boss, otherboss]);

  const layoutProvider = new LayoutProvider((i) => {
    return dataProvider.getDataForIndex(i).type;
  }, (type, dim) => {
    switch(type) {
      case 'NORMAL':
        dim.height = 250;
        dim.width = width * 0.9;
      break;
      default:
        dim.height = 0;
        dim.width = 0;
      break;
    }
  });

  const Item = React.memo(({ name, image, level, translateID, upp, sell_price, dropinfo }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.name}>{I18n.t(translateID)}</Text>
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Image source={image} resizeMode="contain" style={{height: 100, width: 100, marginBottom: 16 }} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.itemFooter}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => openModalUpp(upp)} style={styles.infoBtn}>
          <Feather name="info" size={24} color="#333" />
          <Text>Uppinfo</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => openModalDrop(dropinfo)} style={styles.infoBtn}>
          <Feather name="info" size={24} color="#333" />
          <Text>Dropinfo</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  ));

  const rowRenderer = (type, data) => {
    const { name, image, level, translateID, upp, sell_price, dropinfo } = data.item;
    return (
      <Item name={name} image={image} level={level} translateID={translateID} upp={upp} sell_price={sell_price} dropinfo={dropinfo} />
    )
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RecyclerListView 
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        layoutProvider={layoutProvider}
        rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
        scrollViewProps={{showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false}}
        style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 20}}
      />
      <Portal>

        <ModalDrops DropInfo={dropRef} ref={el => (modals[3] = el)} />
      </Portal>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Modal Flatlist:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';
import faker from 'faker';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export const ModalDrops = React.forwardRef(({ DropInfo }, ref) => {
  console.log('Drops')
  const Item = React.memo(({ name, image, index }) => {
    console.log('rerender');
    return (
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingRight: DropInfo.monster.length -1 === index ? 36 : 0}}>
          <Image source={{uri: faker.image.avatar()}} resizeMode="contain" style={{height: 80, width: 80, borderRadius: 8, marginBottom: 10}} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  });

  function renderItem({ item, index }) {
    return <Item name={item.name} image={item.image} index={index} />
  };

  function key() {
    return Math.random(10000).toString();
  }
  return (
    <Modalize
      ref={ref}
      modalHeight={300}
      flatListProps={{
        data: DropInfo.monster,
        style: {
          padding: 8,
          flex: 1
        },
        renderItem: renderItem,
        horizontal: true,
        ListEmptyComponent: () => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.itemEmpty}>
              <Text>Nicht Droppbar</Text>
            </View>
          )
        },
        keyExtractor: key,
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
        scrollEventThrottle: 16,
        contentContainerStyle: {
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }
      }}
    />
  )
});
```

Video: https://gyazo.com/ff91667f7f0258320317aa7645a046cf
............................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

From what I can see you've one major issue with the way you declare the `Item` component, it's declared inside another component, thus is it redeclared ***any time*** the outer component renders. This effectively unmounts the previous "instance" and mounts a new "instance". It isn't *technically* rerendering, it's just flat out remounted.

## Solution

Don't declare React components inside other React components. In doing so ***and*** trying to memoize any render results won't work since each render cycle creates and mounts a new component. Move the `Item` declaration ***outside*** the components.

Bosses

```
const Item = React.memo(({ .... }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    ...
    </View>
  </View>
));

const Bosses = ({ data }) => {
  ...

  const rowRenderer = (type, data) => {
    const { name, image, level, translateID, upp, sell_price, dropinfo } = data.item;
    return (
      <Item
        name={name}
        image={image}
        level={level}
        translateID={translateID}
        upp={upp}
        sell_price={sell_price}
        dropinfo={dropinfo}
      />
    )
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RecyclerListView 
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        layoutProvider={layoutProvider}
        rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
        scrollViewProps={{showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false}}
        style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 20}}
      />
      <Portal>
        <ModalDrops DropInfo={dropRef} ref={el => (modals[3] = el)} />
      </Portal>
    </View>
  )
};
```

ModalDrops

```
const Item = React.memo(({ name, image, index }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      ...
    </View>
  )
});

export const ModalDrops = React.forwardRef(({ DropInfo }, ref) => {
  function renderItem({ item, index }) {
    return <Item name={item.name} image={item.image} index={index} />
  };

  ...

  return (
    <Modalize
      ref={ref}
      modalHeight={300}
      flatListProps={{
        data: DropInfo.monster,
        style: {
          padding: 8,
          flex: 1
        },
        renderItem: renderItem,
        horizontal: true,
        ListEmptyComponent: () => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.itemEmpty}>
              <Text>Nicht Droppbar</Text>
            </View>
          )
        },
        keyExtractor: key,
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
        scrollEventThrottle: 16,
        contentContainerStyle: {
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }
      }}
    />
  )
});
```

Comment: Its not working. Its always rerenders.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ff91667f7f0258320317aa7645a046cf

Comment: @locklock123 Sorry, it's rather unclear what we're supposed to see in that video. Think you can create a minimal *running* [Expo snack](https://expo.dev/) demo that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: I created an expo snack but only in one file I get error: https://snack.expo.dev/@networker017/tactless-chocolate what means that error ? I cant import anything at the modalDrop.js file

Comment: @locklock123 I have it running [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/tactless-chocolate) but I'm not sure what to do from there. What are the reproduction steps to cause the issue?

Comment: There is an error but I dont get the error on my app. I get this error only in expo snack. I dont know how to solve it. If you want I can upload my app files and send it to you

Comment: @locklock123 What is the error?

Comment: this error: https://preview.redd.it/83asdvgtmlx71.png?width=1624&format=png&auto=webp&s=65c09de4cbef9ab402f036276494f79e2c3d8a94

Comment: @locklock123 I changed the Expo version from v43.0.0 to v42.0.0, and then back to v43 and that error went away. I don't know what caused it but I no longer see that issue in my fork of your snack.

Comment: If you dont have the Issue can you open the app and see the problem with rerender ?

Comment: @locklock123 That's what I was asking you for previously. I have it running in a snack but not sure what to do from there. Are you seeing any error in my snack if you open it?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer I was very ill so I am back now. If I open your snack I get this error:  https://preview.redd.it/83asdvgtmlx71.png?width=1624&format=png&auto=webp&s=65c09de4cbef9ab402f036276494f79e2c3d8a94

Comment: @locklock123 No worries, these things happen. I *did* see that error, initially, but I still don't see that error in the snack now. Did you try what I did in my comment about changing the expo version and back that resolved that error for me.